# What is size of the time variable in C programming?

Tags: c

What is the size of the time variable that are used to show datetime in bits ?
Actually in time.h file the time variable that are used, are they store into int variable or what ?

Answer (score 2):

On GCC (`echo '#include <time.h>' | gcc -E -`):

```
__extension__ typedef long int __time_t;
typedef __time_t time_t;
```

Platform details:

```
Linux stanley 2.6.32-24-generic-pae #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 28 07:39:26 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: printf("%i", sizeof(time_t));

Comment: @nacho4d Don't use `%i` to print the value of `sizeof`. Use `%zu` (C99) or `%lu` and cast the value to `unsigned long` (portable).

Answer (score 2):

Use `sizeof( time_t );` to determine the size in bytes. Then multiply this number with bits per byte (usually 8, but depends on your HW).

Comment: Hint: if you are developing with Microsoft Visual C++ then you can `#define _USE_32_BIT_TIME_T` to enforce time_t to be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

From the C99 standard (7.23.1):
"The range and precision of times representable in clock_t and time_t are 
implementation-deﬁned."

From the standard's perspective it might be an integer, floating point number, Huffman encoded , etc. In practice on most UNIX-like systems it will be a 32 or 64 bit unsigned integer signifing the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (midnight Januari 1 1970).